# Forwarding traffic using iptables

Tags: iptables

I have a server with 3 ips, lets call them A, B, and C.

I need to connect to this server through ip A port 5000 and have my
traffic proxied through ip B.

And, when using IP A port 5001 have my traffic proxied through C.

Is that possible using only iptables or do I need something like squid?

I've tried some nat rules but I had no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good question. You can achieve this in multiple ways. But I will provide only one solution for now. You can use SSH tunneling, then let your applications utilize SOCKS proxy.

Lets assume your traffic is HTTP. From your client machine (laptop in this case), create two SSH tunnels with local listening ports of **5001** and **5002** respectively. One tunnel will breakout through **server-B** and the other will breakout through **server-C** to the internet. The flow goes like this:

**(laptop)** --->**server-A** ----> **server-B** -----> **internet**

**(laptop)** --->**server-A** ----> **server-C** -----> **internet**

From the internet perspective, your traffic will be originating from **server-B** if application is using port **5001** as SOCKS proxy, and **server-C** if application is using port **5002** as SOCKS proxy, while **server-A** remains transparent.

From your laptop, execute the following two commands to create two SSH tunnels, that will bind to `localhost:5001` and `localhost:5002` respectively

```
ssh -f -N -D 5001 -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@server-A" user@server-B
ssh -f -N -D 5002 -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@server-A" user@server-C
```

From your laptop, point your applications (firefox browser for example) to use SOCKS proxy at `127.0.0.1:5001` or `127.0.0.1:5002` accordingly

Reference: [OpenSSH Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts)